# What does it meam a kernel module for wireless card ends with .ko.xz instead of .ko

Tags: fedora, kernel-module

I am on Fedora 38 and I cannot install the kernel module for a Broadcom BCM 43142 Network Controller.
I eventually understood that it is because the module is not correctly signed and that I have to:

1. disable secure boot
2. self sign the module.

After disabling secure boot I could manage to have the module loaded and the wifi working.

But I came back re-enabling secure boot in order to  try self sign the module.

I followed this tutorial [Working with kerned modules](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_Kernel_Modules/) but it didn't worked as I do not fully understand everything.

Particularly the module I have is `/lib/modules/6.4.15-200.fc38.x86_64/extra/wl/wl.ko.xz`

#### Question 1:

Is it normal that it ends with `.ko.xz`?

#### Question 2:

Will the signed module have the same name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it normal that it ends with .ko.xz?

**Yes**.

`.xz` just means it's a compressed binary:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416397/centos7-latest-kernel-moved-from-kernel-ko-to-kernel-ko-xz

> Modules can be compressed using either `gzip` or `xz`. Compression is enabled using the `MODULE_COMPRESS` kernel build option, with `MODULE_COMPRESS_GZIP` or `MODULE_COMPRESS_XZ` to select the compression tool.

---

> Will the signed module have the same name?

By default, **No**.

...though a thoroughly correct answer would depend on how, exactly, you intend to sign and recompress the module file, though:

1. You need to first unpack/decompress the module (i.e. from `.ko.xz` to just `.ko`).
2. Then sign the decompressed module.
3. Then either use the now-signed decompressed module `.ko` as-is, or you can recompress it again back with `xz -f yourModule.ko`

   - If you use *just* `xz -f <output.ko>` then the actual output filename will be `output.ko.xz` - [this is because (by default) the `xz` program will append the compression algorithm's name to the file's name](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xz#:%7E:text=When%20compressing%2C%20the%20suffix%20of%20the%20target%20file%20format%20(.xz%20or%20.lzma)%20is%20appended%20to%20the%20source%20filename%20to%20get%20the%20target%20filename.).

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438954/signing-a-compressed-kernel-module-for-use-with-secure-boot

Comment: OK. I understand this, but can I self sign it in the compressed form ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I could eventually sign my decompressed module but I had to recompress it to have it automatically loaded at startup.